# How do you introduce reactive programming in an existing projet?

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

Potentially "subjective" question : what is a sweet spot for introducing reactive programming (rxjs, bacon, etc...) into an existing, "old-school- MVC-jquery" client side application ?

For example, Promises shine the most if you introduce it in the "API calls" layer of an application (and you can do it one function at a time, returning a Promise instead of accepting a callback - they, it tends to disseminate once everyone in the team gets a few benefits.)

From most of the tutorials I could read, I do not really see where rxjs would shine most. In the widgets (returning stream of events instead of having a 'listener-based' API ?)

Any experience welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say where it will shine the most…

For me, the key feature, is that it allows to describe code in more declarative way instead of writing complicated state machines(as it often happens when working with async logic).

In general, it can be quite useful for anything async for example in UI, or for API calls layer implementation as you mentioned about Promises, but better(promise is just a limited version of observable, except the fact that observable is lazy).

In case of implementing API calls layer, in comparison to promises it will have at least following benefits:

1. subscription to observable is cancellable(disposable) - for example, you can switch between subscriptions for api results without worrying about race conditions with previous api requests... it is as simple as `results = queries.switchMap(q=>doApiCall(q))`
2. it can return multiple values using the same interface - you can easily replace ajax call with subscription to web-socket, and you will not need to change code that is using this.
3. better error handing - it is quite easy with rx to do things like retrying operation n-times before throwing an error, or handling timeout.

I suggest you to watch [Netflix JavaScript Talks - Async JavaScript with Reactive Extensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAZJsxcykPs) by Jafar Husain, there is great examples about where RxJS can be helpful. And likely it would be mostly an answer to your question.